# Issues adding data to Firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm having a strange issue with Firebase, and I can't seem to find any info on it. I'm attempting to add a user object to the database. When I check Firebase, it's created an object with the correct username, but it doesn't add any of the attributes that are Strings, and the 2 double attributes are zero. I've turned off user authentication for now, until I get this working. Here's the relevant code:

```
public class User {

    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String dob;
    public double height;
    public double weight;
    public String gender;

    public User()
    {

    }

    public User(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String DoB, double height, double weight, String gender) {

    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getdob()
    {
        return dob;
    }

    public double getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public double getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    public String getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setdob(String dob)
    {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height)
    {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}

final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference usersRef = database.getReference();
```

...

```
private void registerUser() {

    usersRef.child("testuser").setValue(new User("test@test.com", "password", "First", "Last", "2000/01/01", 172, 75, "Male"));
```

After that completes, if I check Firebase, it shows "users", with an object called "testuser", but the testuser's only attributes are height and weight, both with value 0. If I change height and weight to Strings instead of doubles, nothing at all is added to the database. As far as I can tell, everything is pretty much identical to the Firebase docs, so I'm pretty well stumped. Anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, delete the `static` keyword from your `User` class declaration. Should only be:

```
public class User {}
```

Add the no-argument constructor needed for Firebase.

```
public User() {}
```

Add also the getters and setters for all of your fields.

This how your model class should look like:

```
public class User {
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String dob;
    private double height;
    private double weight;
    private String gender;

    public User() {}

    public User(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String dob, double height, double weight, String gender) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getEmail() {return email;}

    public String getPassword() {return password;}

    public String getFirstName() {return firstName;}

    public String getLastName() {return lastName;}

    public String getDob() {return dob;}

    public double getHeight() {return height;}

    public double getWeight() {return weight;}

    public String getGender() {return gender;}
}
```

Comment: I originally had all of that included, but the same issue. I thought maybe the no args constructor was causing problems for Firebase, or the getters and setters were. The Firebase documentation shows the User object declared as static, but I've tried it both ways with the same results. I just added all of that back in just to be sure, and same results. Original post updated with the current code.

Comment: When the Firebase Realtime Database SDK deserializes objects coming from the database, it requires that any objects in use have a public no-argument constructor that it can use to instantiate the object. Fields in the objects are set by using setter methods or direct access to public members. Also please see my updated answer. See, I have instantiend all fields in the constructor. When using the constructor that users all argument, setters are not mandatory.

Comment: Oh god, I can't believe how stupid a mistake that was. The issue was that I'd forgotten to actually assign values in the constructor. Thanks for the reality check on that. It's working perfectly now.